# Mail merge with attachment

Tags: vba, email, attachment, email-attachments

I have been struggling to do a mail merge on Word VBA, but I have managed to get that right. Now I would like to add a .xls file to every merged document, but can't seem to get it.

My Code so far:

```
Sub SendMerge()

    Dim BLN As Boolean
    BLN = False
     Do While BLN = False

        ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

        With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
            .MailAddressFieldName = "EMail"
            .Destination = wdSendToEmail
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
        .MailSubject = "Samedi 26 Avril 2014"
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    If ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = _
        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
        bDone = True
    End If
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What you mean `add a .xls file` as attachment?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but took a different approach.

Rather than use Word, I used Excel and laid one worksheet out with the boilerplate email text, and on another sheet had one row per recipient with the "merge" fields (name, email address etc) and the name of each file in different columns.

The Excel macro then takes this block and then puts them through a do-while loop and sends the emails one by one. This link will give you the bones of what to do: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

> Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :
>
> In column A : Names of the people
>   In column B : E-mail addresses
>   In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
>
> The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.
>
> ```
> Sub Send_Files()
> 'Working in Excel 2000-2016
> 'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
>     Dim OutApp As Object
>     Dim OutMail As Object
>     Dim sh As Worksheet
>     Dim cell As Range
>     Dim FileCell As Range
>     Dim rng As Range
>
>     With Application
>         .EnableEvents = False
>         .ScreenUpdating = False
>     End With
>
>     Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
>
>     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
>
>     For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
>
>         'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
>         Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")
>
>         If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
>            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
>             Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
>
>             With OutMail
>                 .to = cell.Value
>                 .Subject = "Testfile"
>                 .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
>
>                 For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
>                     If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
>                         If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
>                             .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
>                         End If
>                     End If
>                 Next FileCell
>
>                 .Send  'Or use .Display
>             End With
>
>             Set OutMail = Nothing
>         End If
>     Next cell
>
>     Set OutApp = Nothing
>     With Application
>         .EnableEvents = True
>         .ScreenUpdating = True
>     End With
> End Sub
> ```